# How get the predicted label from a Convolution Neural Net in image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, predict

I have built a `CIFAR-10` image classification model with `Convolution Neural Net` or `CNNs`.

The model fully completed and has got around 59% accuracy, but my problem is that how to get the predicted label from the model. it can predict these classes(10):

```
['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
```

What I'm trying to say is that, for example we give the model a image of a airplane it should predict and show me the label after predicting but **I can't i understand how to obtain the predicted label.**

Here is what i tried, but don't understand what is the output:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), feed_dict={x:ch.test_images, y_true:ch.test_labels, hold_prob:1.0}))
    print(sess.run(tf.argmax(y_true, 1), feed_dict={x:ch.test_images, y_true:ch.test_labels, hold_prob:1.0}))
```

OUPUT:

```
[0 0 0 ... 0 3 3]
[3 8 8 ... 5 1 7]
```

**SPECFICATIONS**:
TENSORFLOW VERSION: 1.15.2
EDITOR: Google Colab
OS: Windows 7

**GOOGLE COLAB FILE LINK**:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NpYGWvo9bNG0SJsFJ6R3se46b1ovDUX8/view?usp=sharing
**NOTE:** The link is outdated

If you want any more information or wan't to ask any queries about the question please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting are the `indexes` of the classes, that is the number each class is represented by. In your example, 0 means 'airplane', 1 means 'automobile' and so on.

To get the names you just need to access the class names.

```
classes=['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    idxs = sess.run(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), feed_dict={x:ch.test_images, y_true:ch.test_labels, hold_prob:1.0}))
    labels = [classes[idx] for idx in idxs]
    print(labels)
```

Comment: But @charlie is it possible that i get the label and the image at the same time, basically what i mean is  on the top i will see the original image and on the bottom the predicted label, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean in terms of visualization? If so, sure, you can use any image ploting utility like matplotlib, and then iterate over the images and the predicted labels and add the label as the title of the figure, something like: `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image);matplotlib.pyplot.title(label)`